# DynamoDB InternalError - exception while calling dynamodb.Query: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When executing a query with DynamoDB, the query fails with exception:

```
errorCode: InternalError
errorType: "Service"
errorMessage: exception while calling dynamodb.Query: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Example query:

```java
final var query = new QueryRequest()
                .withIndexName(Indexes.SORT_BY_JOB_COUNT)
                .withScanIndexForward(false)
                .withKeyConditionExpression(AttributeKeys.JOB_ID_MONTH + " = :jid_mth")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(Map.of(":jid_mth", new AttributeValue("1_12"))
                .withLimit(limit);
```

Why is this query failing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `QueryRequest` is missing the tableName.

This can be fixed with:

```java
    query.setTableName("my-table-name")
```

The underlying error of `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` is a red herring, and just implementation detail on Amazon's side. Aside: that's a Python error.